# Display count of checked check boxes in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gridview that creates check boxes.

I would like to display on my page how many checkboxes have been clicked without the use of a button. I would like for it to be displayed dynamically.

So if I click on 3 checkboxes I will see the number 3 being displayed. (displayed inside div tags would be ideal).

Comment: how is this question edited by someone different?

Comment: @jruddell See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges In particular, look at the "retag questions" and "edit questions and answers" privileges.  Note that all I did in this case was remove some irrelevant tags -- I would have made a comment if it had been anything more.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
$('#gridview input:checkbox').live('click', function(){
   $('#count').html($('#gridviewcontainer input:checkbox:checked').length); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to do this without being able to see your code, but something like this should work:

```
$('#gridview').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function() {
    var count = $('#gridview').find('input:checkbox:checked').length;

    $('div#count').html(count);
});
```

Comment: Im new to jquery so anything helps, can I email you my code for your viewing?